# Setup machine to machine (Console to WebAPI) authorization with identity server3

Tags: oauth-2.0, cors, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver3

I am trying to setup authorization from a console app to a WebAPI endpoint using identityserver3 as the authorization service. This is not a self hosted API and it will be public facing. I've tried to follow through the documentation on identity server and I have the API running and IdentityServer running independently.  Where I am having trouble is getting the api route to check for authorization and request/receive the access token from identity server.

Within identity server I have the startup.cs file defined as:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
                {
                    var corsPolicyService = new DefaultCorsPolicyService()
                    {
                        AllowAll = true
                    };

                    var defaultViewServiceOptions = new DefaultViewServiceOptions();
                    defaultViewServiceOptions.CacheViews = false;

                    var idServerServiceFactory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
                        .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                        .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get())  
                        .UseInMemoryUsers(Users.Get());   

                    idServerServiceFactory.CorsPolicyService = new
                        Registration<IdentityServer3.Core.Services.ICorsPolicyService>(corsPolicyService);

                    idServerServiceFactory.ConfigureDefaultViewService(defaultViewServiceOptions);

                    var options = new IdentityServerOptions
                    {
                        Factory = idServerServiceFactory,
                        SiteName = "Sumbission Security Token Service",
                        SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),
                        IssuerUri = "https://samplesubmission/identity",
                        PublicOrigin = "https://localhost:44306",                    
                    };

                    idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(options);
                });
            }

            X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
            {
                return new X509Certificate2(
                    string.Format(@"{0}\certificates\idsrv3test.pfx",
                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), "idsrv3test");
            }
```

And within web.config for IdSrv I added

WebAPI contains the following

```
public class SampleController: ApiController
    {
        [Route("test")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
            {
            var caller = User as ClaimsPrincipal;//grants access to claim from access token

            Message msg = new Message
            {
                Msg = "Connction made with secure api" + DateTime.Now,
               // Client = caller.FindFirst("client_id").Value
            };
            return Json(msg);
        }
    }

    public class Message
    {
        public string Msg { get; set; }
        public string Client { get; set; }
    }
```

startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(
             new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
             {
                 Authority = "https://localhost:44306/identity",
                 RequiredScopes = new[] { "vendorsubmission" },
             });
        }
    }
```

Disabling OWIn in API I can make calls such as `https://localhost:44307/test`  and hit the endpoint.

The Console app contains this in program.cs

```
class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var response = GetClientToken();
            CallApi(response);
        }

        static void CallApi(TokenResponse response)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.SetBearerToken(response.AccessToken);
            System.Console.WriteLine(client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:44307/test").Result);
        }

        static TokenResponse GetClientToken()
        {
            var client = new TokenClient(
                "http://localhost:44306/identity/connect/token",
                "samplecnsl", //client name
                "F621F470-9731-4A25-80EF-67A6F7C5F4B8"); //secret

            return  client.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("vendorsubmission").Result;

        }
    }
```

When this executes the task errors out (the task was canceled) . I get the message The resource requested does not support GET. I thought this would be a cors issue but I have CORS enabled on the identity server and I even added to the http protocols in web.config:

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to get the console application to retrieve the token from the identity server? I feel it's an authorization issue. I am running this locally in in Dev IISExpres and I am currently using the certs provided by the identity server source.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the so called client credentials grant

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4

Here's a sample for it using identityserver3

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/ConsoleClientCredentialsClient

CORS is unrelated to this scenario, since it only applies to browser-based clients. So it is probably some issue with your web server.

Comment: just as a follow up the issue was with the certificate. Authentication was failing because the current cert was SHA1 and the encryption was using sha256. Updating the cert to a SHA256 crypto resolved the issue.